# about install auto-sklearn at colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, auto-sklearn

I tried to install `auto-sklearn` at google colab, but it made an error. I don't have any clue to fix it. Please help me.

```
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Okay, did some digging. It can't install `scikit-learn==0.24.2`. Tried installing by downloading the wheel which is not supported by Colab's Python version (3.10.12). [Here](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.24.0/#files), you can see the latest wheel is built with version 3.9. I'm not sure if there's a solution other than installing Python 3.9 and using the wheel.

Comment: https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/1690#issuecomment-1739916112 this worked for me